# laravel db update is not performing

Tags: php, laravel

One column update query is not performing. the added data is not updating in the database.

my view:

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/add-edit-spe')) ;?>
 /* form elements */
```

Admincontroller

```
    public function postAddEditSpe()  
         {
    Input::flash();
    $rules = array(                    
            'spe_name' => 'required|unique:spec',
            'description' => 'required'
    );    
    $messages = array(
            'spe_name.required' => 'Spe name is required',
            'spe_name.unique:' => 'Spe name should be unique',
            'description.required' => 'Spe description is required',
    );
     $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
 if ($validator->fails())
            {
                dd($validator->errors);
    /*  shows the same page */
}
 else{
     $data['spe_id']=Input::get('spe_id');
                $data['spe_name']=Input::get('spe_name');
                $data['spe_content']=Input::get('description');
                $data['r_tags']=Input::get('r_tags');
                $data['f_spe']=Input::get('f_spe');
                $data['r_spe']=implode(",",Input::get('r_id'));
    DB::table('spec')->where('spe_id','=',$data['spe_id'])->update(array('spe_name' => $data['spe_name'],'spe_content' => $data['spe_content'],'f_spe' => $data['f_spe'],'related_spe' => $data['r_spe'],'r_tags' => $data['r_tags']));
    }
      }
```

the validation error shows :

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Validation\Validator::$errors
```

the output of   `dd($validator->messages());`   is:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)#895 (2) { ["messages":protected]=> array(1) { ["spe_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(43) "The spe name has already been taken." } } ["format":protected]=> string(8) ":message" }
```

the else part is not executed becuase of validation failure. can anyone tell me what this validation error means? why it occurs?

**Edition i made**

I re-arranged the validation rules for insert and update like this:

```
if(Input::get('speciality_id')!=0){
          // Updation
           $rules = array(                    
                'speciality_name' => 'required|exists:speciality',
                'description' => 'required'
        );  
        }
        else{
        // Insert
        $rules = array(                    
                'speciality_name' => 'required|unique:speciality',
                'description' => 'required'
        );  
       }
```

In this case updation is working, insertion are working. but only one case is not satisfying 
it is "if the db contains an entry with name "abc" and "xyz". we will check whether these are unique while inserting. but if i select "xyz" for Edit and changes its name to "abc" and click update. two "abc" will occur. the "exists" rule satisfied. This scenario must not happen. What should i do to avoid this test case.??

Comment: did you debug that laravel gets all the required post params from form?

Comment: @Serg:  i have marked debug in app.php as true. but no errors were shown in the site. (please forgive me..i just started learning laravel today)

Comment: Can you post the output when you add the line `dd($data)` right before DB::table('spec')...->update()?

Comment: @soulkphp: hi.. an edition made in the post. please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

For updation use this rule . Pass current row id to rules . it will do the charm

```
$rules = array(                    
        'spe_name' => 'required|unique:spec,:id',
        'description' => 'required'
 )
```

For more information [check](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=70804)

Comment: then how can i check if during updation the entered name is unique. that is, for example if there is already an entry named "abc" and i took the entry "xyz" for update. and i edit its name to "abc" and click update. this scenario must not happen.

Comment: remove unique:spec . if you don't want unique check.

Comment: i have edited the comment. please check that scenario.

Comment: You can check this in front end even. You can use ajax for checking uniqueness of field . let user post form only if it is unique and verified from your ajax check .

Comment: Even with your current code . if you are posting unique values to update then if should be working. It should go to else part as you are expecting.

Comment: i made the update to work by using "exists" in the rule instead of unique and wrote another rule with unique for insert . but in this case the scenario that i said first occurs. thats the problem now i'm facing.

Comment: You mean you first use exists and then unique (same time) for update validation.

Comment: i have updated my post with the new rule that i used for update and insert

Comment: why don't you use unique rule for both edit and insert. Ultimately you want to insert unique values in db. So where is confusion.

Comment: when i used unique rule for edit the query is not executing. validation error occurs. that i was mentioned in the first portion of my question. to solve it i re arranged the rules. is there any other better way?

Comment: Validation error will occur only if you will not provide unique value.

Comment: Use updated rule for updation. Use primary key in place of :id